# ERROR: API Call unsuccessful. Status code returned 401- Amazon Web Service

Tags: amazon-web-services

I just want to create environment but fail with terminal mac.

> eb create django-env
>   Creating application version archive
>   "app-170608_112505". 
>   Uploading django-tutorial/app-170608_112505.zip
>   to S3. This may take a while. Upload Complete. 
>   **ERROR: API Call unsuccessful. Status code returned 401**

Everyone know what is this problem?

Comment: Did you manage to understand what was the problem for this one? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This error can occur when you try to create an Elastic Beanstalk environment within the first few hours of creating an AWS account. Using the --verbose flag will reveal an OptInRequired error when Elastic Beanstalk tries to create an EC2 instance.

Try navigating to the EC2 dashboard in the AWS console. If you don't see the normal dashboard then your account is still being verified.